# SQL Server 2012 CU7 Causing SSIS XML Task - XSLT Transform Output to Variable Error

Tags: xml, xslt, ssis, sql-server-2012

I currently have a SSIS Package that performs a webservice call returning xml to a variable. The XML - Task then performs an XSLT Transformation against the xml and proceeds to the data flow tasks. This was working prior to the installation of SQL Server 2012 CU7. Now whenever the package is executed it errors on the XSLT Transform with this error in the sysssislog:

An error occurred with the following error message: "Cannot access a closed Stream.".

If the output of the XML - Task is changed to a file it successfully executes.

Looking at the updates in CU7 I found [KB3063438](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3063438) .  To me it seems like they have corrected one issue, that I was not encountering, and caused another. I should also mention that the package was executing successfully on my local machine in SQL Server Data Tools. To test I installed CU7, since I was on CU6, and now I receive the same error on my local machine as well.

Is anyone else having this issue? Or has anyone found a work around or a hotfix other than changing the package to output to a file? I have been unsuccessful at either and I would prefer not to output the data to a file first or to rollback CU7.

**Update. I rolled CU7 back on my local machine and the package is executing successfully once more.

Comment: This is a situation where I'd contact MS Support. You had a working thing, you installed a CU and it's now broken. They need to know that it's borked and might provide you a patch to resolve this situation until CU8 comes out.

Comment: For what it's worth, SQL Server 2012 SP1 CU8 came out today. It's kismet!

Comment: @billinkc where are you seeing this CU8? And did you mean SQL SP2 instead of SP1? The only thing I can find is CU7 and MS still lists CU7 as the most recent CU for SQL Server 2012 SP2 on their site. Thanks!

Comment: My apologies, I misread the release notes (private MS distribution list). There were two releases announced yesterday but they were both for 2014. Sorry to get your hopes up

Comment: No worries. I have actually opened a support ticket with MS. Once I get a resolution I will update this post too.

Comment: Hi, any updates on this by any chance? We are getting the same issue on SQL Server 2012 SP3. It was working before on SQL Server 2012 SP2 (without CU's).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up opening a support ticket with Microsoft. The result of which found that there is a Bug in CU7 for SQL Server 2012 SP2 with the XML Task when performing an XSLT transform and storing the output to a variable. Until a patch/hotfix/CU8 they suggested two workarounds.

1. Change the output option of the XML Task to go to a file connection rather than a variable.
2. Rollback CU7 on the production server that will be executing the SSIS Package.

Once they reach back out to me with the patch/hotfix/CU8 I will update or comment on this answer.

*Update: I confirmed with MS the fix is not in CU8. I will update again once they inform me what hotfix/CU/SP it eventually ends up in.*

*Update 2: When SP3 came out I confirmed with MS that the fix is not included. The only thing real feedback so far is that they confirmed it is a bug and it is on their project list. No ETA. I got tired of waiting for the fix since it was holding up our capability to patch one of our servers and ended up writing a c# script task to perform the xml transform. Alternatively you could still use the XML Task and set the output to a file. That does work. Only when you set the output to a variable does it error.*

***Final Update: I have not confirmed this personally yet, but it looks like Microsoft has fixed this in the following SPs/CUs:***

- **SQL Server 2012 SP3 CU5**
- **SQL Server 2014 CU13**
- **SQL Server 2014 SP1 CU9**
- **SQL Server 2014 SP2 CU3**
- **SQL Server 2014 SP3 CU5**
- **SQL Server 2016 CU4**
- **SQL Server 2016 SP1 CU2**

**[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3115741](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3115741/fix-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-error-when-an-xml-task-fails-in-sql-server)**

Comment: Fix seems to be not in SP3 either.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this same issue.  However, after working with Microsoft, we discovered this issue can be be resolved by upgrading to SQL Server 2012 SP3 with CU5.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3180915